# pl/sql: how to put the values of all rows if exceptions is possible?

Tags: oracle, plsql, exception

I have procedure that transferring values from one table to another.

```
create table t_num(num number(10,2));
create table t_str(str varchar2(10));
insert into t_str (str) values('23');
insert into t_str (str) values('2 3');
insert into t_str (str) values('2 3,3 2');
insert into t_str (str) values('2 3,3 223');
commit;

create or replace procedure put_to_t_num
as
    type t_num_t is table of t_num%rowtype index by binary_integer;
    tn t_num_t;
    n binary_integer := 0;
begin
    delete from t_num;
    --tn := t_num_t();
    for rec in ( select * from t_str )
    loop
        n := n + 1;
        --tn.extend;
        tn(n).num := to_number( regexp_replace( regexp_replace( rec.str, ',', '.'), ' ', '' ) );
    end loop;

    forall i in 1..n
        insert into t_num (
            num
        ) values (
            tn(i).num
        );
        --commit;
end;
```

the string

```
tn(n).num := to_number( regexp_replace( regexp_replace( rec.str, ',', '.'), ' ', '' ) );
```

may throw exception VALUE_ERROR.

But I need to insert all values in this code, e.g. if exception then insert 0 instead of real value, that do not converting (something like try-catch in other languages).

How can I do this in my code?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve: CallableStatement executing returns error "ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29286665/how-to-resolve-callablestatement-executing-returns-error-ora-06502-pl-sql-nu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this single line:

```
tn(n).num := to_number( regexp_replace( regexp_replace( rec.str, ',', '.'), ' ', '' ) );
```

use this sub-block to handle exception:

```
begin 
  tn(n).num := to_number( regexp_replace( regexp_replace( rec.str, ',', '.'), ' ', '' ) );
exception when VALUE_ERROR
  then tn(n).num := 0;
end;
```

Comment: thanks, but ... I have success on browser console, but I have no data in table t_num after call of this procedure

Comment: Did you turn on `commit`? In your code it was commented.

Comment: thank you one more time, it was another problem with nls_numeric_characters, your answer is the best on my question (I had a problem with internet connection to say it earlier)